# Converting Irregular Tabular Information to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdf, tabular

I'm trying to convert tabular information in PDF to a pandas dataframe.

The conditions of the tabular information is as follows:

- The tabular information exist across many pages but in the same table structure and heading on every page.
- The data rows consist of 2 parts - 1) master row followed by 2) child row.
- There are master rows without child rows.
- When the child row exist, there could be 1 or 2 child rows.
- There is a column in child row that could be empty and needs to be inherited from the master row.  When the column in child row exists, the same column is empty in the master column.
- There's a unique keyword in the child row that can be differentiated from the master row.

For example, the following is typical example of the rows:

| Name | Code A | Code B | More Columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Master 0 |  | 0123450 |  |
| Master 1 |  |  |  |
| Child 1-1 | 012345 | 0123451 |  |
| Master 2 |  | 0123452 |  |
| Child 2-1 | 012346 |  |  |
| Master 3 |  |  |  |
| Child 3-1 | 012347 | 0123463 |  |
| Child 3-2 | 012348 | 0123464 |  |

The goal is to have unique list of child rows from all the pages as follows:

| Master | Name | Code A | Code B | More Columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Master 1 | Child 1-1 | 012345 | 0123451 |  |
| Master 2 | Child 2-1 | 012346 | 0123452 |  |
| Master 3 | Child 3-1 | 012347 | 0123463 |  |
| Master 3 | Child 3-2 | 012348 | 0123464 |  |

To convert the tabular information from PDF, I have used tabula read_pdf with lattice=True (as the name column can have a carriage return when it's longer than the width of the cell).  I was trying to come up with a code to handle the irregularity but unable to generate the expected format.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to [forward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) certain columns.

```
child = df["Name"].str.startswith("Child")
df.loc[~child, "Master"] = df["Name"]
```

```
cols = ["Code A", "Code B", "Master"]
df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
```

```
>>> df[child]
        Name   Code A    Code B  More Columns    Master
2  Child 1-1  12345.0  123451.0           NaN  Master 1
4  Child 2-1  12346.0  123452.0           NaN  Master 2
6  Child 3-1  12347.0  123463.0           NaN  Master 3
7  Child 3-2  12348.0  123464.0           NaN  Master 3
```